# vertical layout little issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout (vertical) and it should contain 3 elements in the following order: textview, listview and button. The listview could be really high so in order to keep all the 3 elements visible I put the 3 elements each one inside another layout. So my structure is like:

```
linear layout (vertical)
  linear layout (horizontal)
    textview
  linear layout (vertial)   *
    listview
  relative layout
    button
```

In order to get it working I set a fixed height to the vertical linearlayout which only contains the listview (*) but I know it is a bad choice because on bigger devices there will be a lot of empty space. How can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: try with the solution I have posted, that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

User percentage values for the LinearLayout(*), so they take up a percentage of the parent's height,

and for the rest, if you want them to take up remaining space, add attribute: `android:layout_weight:1`;

Comment: ok I'll try, the problem is a little hard to explain here and even is difficult to try with the emulator because the list is populated after an http call to my webserver, so probably it's better if I fill a list and open the emulator with a bigger screen.
Thanks ;)

Comment: If I remember correctly, listView takes care of its own scrolling, so it should be fine even it you give it a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your layout this way :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Header Text" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mTextView" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:id="@+id/listview"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```